# Linq2SQL, EDMX, interfaces (Preparing for a TDD enabled project!)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is there an easy way to create a Linq to SQL class for my "DomainModel" off an EDMX (Entity Framework)?

I assume this IS what I want to do...

At the moment I am guessing that if I have my `myModel.edmx` which is generated from SQL DB which contains an entity/table `Levels` and I want to create an interface for it.

Currently I have a "levels.cs" inside an "Entities" folder inside the DomainModel project. 
This should link to the Entity Framework and looks like this:

`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DomainModel.Entities;
using System.Data.Linq;
using System.Data.Linq.Mapping;

namespace DomainModel.Entities
{
    [Table(Name="Levels")]
    public class level
    {
        [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true, IsDbGenerated = true, AutoSync = AutoSync.OnInsert)]
        public System.Guid Id { get; internal set; }
        [Column] string UserId { get; set; }
        [Column]public int ScenId { get; set; }
        ...other fields...
    }

}
```

`
Is it looking correct so far? Is there an easier way to auto generate these files? I take it the next step is to create an interface?
The end goal is to develop this project using a test driven dev approach. The test part is fine, I've just never had to develop in this fashion before

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at T4 to generate files.

When you use Entity Framework you talk about Linq to Entities and not about linq to SQL

Comment: I am currently using the `ADO.NET DbContext Generator` which I can create interfaces fairly easily with. If I am striving for a Test Driven Environment in MVC. Now I have interfaces for my Main tables, what would be the next step? I dont quite understand how they link to the EDMX